# Unable to Create Pod in Minikube Error: unknown shorthand flag

Tags: kubectl, minikube

$ minikube kubectl create -f hello-app-deployment.yaml
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f
See 'minikube kubectl --help' for usage.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOHUD.png)

where hello-app-deployment.yaml is the deployment manifest file being saved in a working directory.

I tried saving the same manifest file in my home directory, but encountering the same ERROR.

Is there any minikube or kubectl libaries missing ?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are missing the `--`, try with:

```
minikube kubectl -- create -f hello-app-deployment.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say, try installing the kubectl CLI and try with this command

```
kubectl apply -f ~/<filepath>
```

You can download the tool from the official website:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/